# In CSS, does border-radius have to be in the same class as the border it modifies if they are both classed in the same div tag?

Tags: html, class, border, css

I have this HTML code:

```
        <p class="categoryButton glowing-border">
        <div class="facilityMaintenance" />
        <div class="lighting" />
        <div class="powerSweeping" />
        <div class="landscaping" />
  </p>
```

And this CSS:

```
.categoryButton {
position: fixed;
opacity: 0.5;
z-index: 100;
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: blue;
width: 17.5em;
height: 17.5em;
left: 50%;
}
.facilityMaintenance {
margin-left: -17.6em;
top: 6em;
border-radius: 100% 0% 0% 0%;
}

.lighting {
    border-radius: 0% 100% 0% 0%;
    top: 6em;
}

.powerSweeping {
    margin-left: -17.6em;
    border-radius: 0% 0% 0% 100%;
    top: 23.3em;
}

.landscaping {
    border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 0%;
    top: 23.3em;
}

.glowing-border {
    border: 2px solid #dadada;
}

.glowing-border:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

What could be wrong? Also, for some reason, when I test it in the browser, "top" and "margin-left" don't work. Why is that? 
Thank you for all your help!

By the way, I'm using dreamweaver, and it doesn't render border-radius, and it screws a lot of things up on some of my pages. It doesn't handle left: 50; or margin: auto; well either. Is that common? I'm just testing in my browser instead of Dreamweaver.

Comment: Add your jsFiddle to see the problem please.

Comment: You can't put `div` elements in a `p` element, and self-closing syntax does not work on `div` elements unless you're rendering XHTML.

Comment: But to answer your question: `border-radius` acts on the same border box as all the other border properties do, so they have to be on the same element. If the same element has more than one class and you're applying border styles to all those classes, then it's equivalent to having them all on the same class (specificity notwithstanding).

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, the `<p>` has the border, but the `<div>`s have the border-radius.  You need to have border and border-radius acting on the same elements, even if they are set in different classes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, and it makes sense, but it seemed to mess it up more. It put the border somewhere off of the divs, and the divs still aren't separated. Not sure if I mentioned that before. Not really sure what to do...

Comment: @GabeCaterson - please create a jsFiddle with what you tried, and I'll edit it to show how I intended this to work.